# Oracle function re-write in SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have an Oracle function that needs to be converted to SQL-Server function

This is the Oracle Function:

```
FUNCTION check_education(in_crs_code IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN BOOLEAN IS
    v_bool            BOOLEAN := FALSE;
    v_dummy            VARCHAR2(1);

    CURSOR find_education  IS
        SELECT 'x'
          FROM KU_LIBRARY_EDUCATION_EXTLOAN
         WHERE UPPER(course_code) = UPPER(in_crs_code) AND in_use = 'Y';
BEGIN
    OPEN find_education;

    FETCH find_education     INTO v_dummy;

    IF find_education%FOUND THEN
        v_bool        := TRUE;
    ELSE
        v_bool        := FALSE;
    END IF;

    CLOSE find_education;

    RETURN (v_bool);
END check_education;
```

This is what I have written in SQL-Server to replicate Oracle function:

```
   CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[check_education](@in_crs_code VARCHAR(4000))
    RETURNS BIT AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @v_bool BIT = 0;
    DECLARE @v_dummy VARCHAR(1);

    DECLARE find_education CURSOR LOCAL  FOR
        SELECT 'x'
          FROM [dbo].[KU_LIBRARY_EDUCATION_EXTLOAN]
         WHERE UPPER(course_code) = UPPER(@in_crs_code) 
         AND in_use = 'Y';

    OPEN find_education;

    FETCH find_education INTO @v_dummy;

    IF @@CURSOR_ROWS >1 BEGIN
        SET @v_bool = 1;
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        SET @v_bool = 0;
    END 

    CLOSE find_education;
    DEALLOCATE find_education;

    RETURN (@v_bool);
END;
```

I would expect the SQL server function to return 1 if the cursor returns 'x' but i'm getting 0. Anu help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you need @@CURSOR_ROWS > 0 (not 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using an inline table valued function instead of a scalar function. To make sure this is an inline table valued function it MUST be a single select statement. This means there can't be loops and other stuff. Fortunately this query does not actually need any loops. A simple count will return the number of rows. And any value other than 0 when converted to a bit will always be 1.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[check_education]
(
    @in_crs_code VARCHAR(4000)
) RETURNS table as return

    SELECT CourseExists = convert(bit, count(*))
    FROM [dbo].[KU_LIBRARY_EDUCATION_EXTLOAN]
    WHERE UPPER(course_code) = UPPER(@in_crs_code) 
        AND in_use = 'Y';
```

Comment: Glad that works for you. You might consider marking this as the answer so others know it worked you.

Answer (score -1):

This is a mere `EXISTS` thing, so we could try

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[check_education](@in_crs_code VARCHAR(4000)) RETURNS BIT AS
BEGIN
  RETURN EXISTS ( <query> )
END;
```

But as far as I know, SQL Server doesn't accept this (though I cannot say why not - maybe it's because of their lack of a real boolean; Oracle doesn't accept it, because `EXISTS` is no keyword in their PL/SQL programming language).

So we'd use `IF`/ `THEN`/ `ELSE`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[check_education](@in_crs_code VARCHAR(4000)) RETURNS BIT AS
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 'x' 
    FROM ku_library_education_extloan
    WHERE UPPER(course_code) = UPPER(in_crs_code) AND in_use = 'Y'
  )
    RETURN 1
  ELSE
    RETURN 0
  END
END;
```

There may be errors, because I've never coded a stored procedure in T-SQL, but anyway, you get the idea.